how to navigate the path of the media image in django?
[product.html main page images are not rendered.[setting.py of main project](https://i.sstatic.net/kZOodmRb.png)] main page view not showing image .(https://i.sstatic.net/UFhbgqED.png)
I checked all url.py and views name and import everything still don't know how to fix this error.
It showing no media found and cannot configure ecommerce settings.py url.py.


Make sure that you have set the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your settings.py because if you haven't set that then defult is empty which not serve media files as you intend.
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Just cross verify that DEBUG = True in your settings.py



If you've configured MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT correctly, you should be able to access your media files by going to localhost:8000/media/<image_path>.
and to render in template:
<img src="{{ my_model_instance.media_file.url }}" alt="Media File">

and models.py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')

